# WP ALL IMPORT i want to do a basic php function with the php editor

Tags: php, wpallimport

I need help with the php function editor in wp all import. It's a very long time i haven't used PHP so i hope you can help me a little !

I guess I need to use the php function editor for my problem.

With WP ALL IMPORT, i get this example in my xml file :
Jérôme xxx
On my website, the data about all agents is managed by an agent module (instead of just showing the name of the agent, it shows a photo, a name, a phone, etc... for each person)
By auto-detecting, WP ALL IMPORT gives me :
(name) agent (value-serialized) key 0 value 24756
This value is set specifically for the agent Jérome xxx

I have about 6 or 7 agents in my database with each a different value. From what i saw, i don't think i can just set this thing with the "serialized" field option in wpallimport.

So i guess i need to use the php function editor. I was quickly looking for in the "similar questions" and i took this example from the lef :

```
<?php
function ae_stock_change($x) {     * function agent($x) { 
if (StockLevel == "Green")         * if (agent == "Jérome xxx")  
    $x = 12;                       *     $x = 24756
elseif (StockLevel == "Amber")     * elseif (agent == "Jonathan xxx")
    $x = 3;                        *     $x = 88888
else $x = 0;                       * etc...
return $x;
?>
```

UPDATING :
It's a real estate multicast application ! (sorry for my english if it's not correct). Each time we fill an real estate ad on netty app, the xml file is updated.

Then on WP, we have several modules and which one is "propriétés" (real estate property) and another one is "agent" where every fields is identified with Advanced Custom Fields. I identified for each agent the value of the post created by wordpress (by example, agent "Jerome" is 24756, etc..).

So on WPallimport, when i import the xml file, by example, i can have 15 differents goods and each good can have a different agent. In the xml file, i have this tag  Jérôme xxx or another name inside. In the field "agent" of WPALLIMPORT, if i use autodetecting, it modifies field options by "serialized", it sets key to 0 and fix the value of the first agent created "24756" because the tag in xml file is different from ACF field(=agent) i guess.

So the need of my function is to tell WPALLIMPORT that:
 IF the tag "nom à afficher" from xml file is "Jonathan", then the value must be "25555"
ELSEIF the tag gives me "Jerome", then the value must be "24756"
ELSEIF etc...

Finally on each real estate ad on the website, it increments for each ad a "window" with agent information coming from the "agent" module.

I hope it's not so hard to understand !

Thank you

Hedredo

Comment: _“From what i saw, i don't think i can just set this thing with the "serialized" field option in wpallimport.”_ - we don’t know what exactly you saw, so give us a proper example of what the relevant database field(?) contains for such an agent to begin with, when it was set by the plugin. And also what exactly you are _importing_.

Comment: I have updated the post, see at the end of the original post

Comment: If you don’t have to many of these agent-number combinations, then you could do this simply by configuring a mapping, http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/custom-fields/mapping/ Or, if you want to use PHP, put the data into an array - agent name as key, number as value - then you can easily look up the value to return.

Comment: Thankk you so much, i understood that i can put   the tag in the value and then translate the data into the tag into my value ^^ It should do the work for most of my needs for this import except maybe check boxes. Can you also help me for this on this post or shoud i do a new post ? thanks by advance